# Access a Mac via hostname.local from a Windows PC

Tags: windows, mac, networking, dns

I'm the only Windows user at my workplace full of Macs. Of course, being the only person with a different setup, I'm often left to do my own IT troubleshooting.

The issue I have is that everyone's computer is accessible via `{hostname}.local` (eg, foobar.local), but when I type that in, the host can't be resolved.

I've found that if I change the `.local` part to my "Connection-specific DNS Suffix" then it works:

```
ping foobar.local            // Ping request could not find host foobar.local

ping foobar.corp.mywork.com  // <-- now works. Resolves to 10.0.10.25
```

Simply switching to use the full part isn't an option (long story, but just trust me on that one).

So, **how do I get Windows to resolve `hostname.local` addresses?**

Comment: You need a Multicast DNS resolver for Windows. I don't know what's available so this isn't an answer, but perhaps this would help as a search term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Bonjour for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999), available from Apple. It's now confusingly named "Bonjour Print Services for Windows". It includes a Multicast DNS resolver, which will handle those ".local" addresses.

Comment: This makes ping work but I can't access the computer in Explorer by hostname.local. Maybe that is a whole separate problem.